# How to use / see refunded gas in ETH blockchain?

Tags: gas, cpp-ethereum, gas-refund

I buy a GAStoken contract which requires say 21000 GAS at 1 Gwei and later when we delete/destroy the contract when the Gwei is around 50. I understand that we will get around 50% refund of GAS at the current Gwei.  The idea behind this is to use the refunded GAS to lower the transaction costs for subsequent transactions. Can someone point me as to how to claim/use this refund?

I'm a newbie to this space and AFAIK GAS cannot be stored. Please correct if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

On `revert`, unused gas is returned to you right after transaction was mined and on `throw` all gas is "eaten". Failed transactions are still included into block so miners get paid for it.
The `gwei` you set has nothing to do with the amount of gas being returned, it only defines your position in "mining queue", so the more gwei you set, the faster your transaction will be mined/executed on blockchain.
Oh and you can check used gas on https://etherscan.io/ by entering your transaction hash.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using myetherwallet and have mined gastoken for reduced txn fees. I want to know how the refunded gas can be used to lower the txn costs for my upcoming ETH transaction. Also I'm unable to use some of the functions listed under the gastoken contract. Any help on how to use that is also useful.

Comment: @Maxpeinas, I guess his question is more about gastoken.io, some kind of 3rd party service that returns gas to its users, somehow.

Comment: Thanks @Nulik. In general, I would also like to know how the refunded gas is treated.